# How to test MvvmCross MvxCommand<int> with NUnit

Tags: parameters, nunit, mvvmcross, execute, icommand

How do I write a NUnit test for MvvmCross MvxCommand when my command needs CommandParameter of type integer.

```
testListViewModel.EditCommand.Execute(null);
```

This one is not an option since i have this ViewModel. CanExecute proceeds if parameter is passed.

```
public class TestListViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly ITestService _testService;
    private readonly IDialogService _dialogService;
    public TestListViewModel(ITestService testService, IDialogService dialogService)
    {
        _testService = testService;
        _dialogService = dialogService;
    }   

    public MvxCommand<int> EditCommand { get { return new MvxCommand<int>(Edit, id => id > 0); } }      

    private void Edit(int asTestID) { ShowViewModel<TestViewModel>(new { asTestID }); }
}
```

I use NUnit + Moq + Cirrious.MvvmCross.Test.Core references in my test project and have this structure.

```
public class MockDispatcher : MvxMainThreadDispatcher, IMvxViewDispatcher
{
    public readonly List<MvxViewModelRequest> Requests = new List<MvxViewModelRequest>();
    public readonly List<MvxPresentationHint> Hints = new List<MvxPresentationHint>();
    public bool RequestMainThreadAction(Action action)
    {
        action();
        return true;
    }

    public bool ShowViewModel(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        Requests.Add(request);
        return true;
    }

    public bool ChangePresentation(MvxPresentationHint hint)
    {
        Hints.Add(hint);
        return true;
    }
}

[TestFixture]
class TestListViewModelTest : MvxIoCSupportingTest
{
    [Test]
    public void TestListViewModel_OnEdit_ShowTestViewModel()
    {
        //Arrange
        base.ClearAll();

        var mockDispatcher = new MockDispatcher();
        Ioc.RegisterSingleton<IMvxViewDispatcher>(mockDispatcher);
        Ioc.RegisterSingleton<IMvxMainThreadDispatcher>(mockDispatcher);

        var mockDialogService = new Mock<IDialogService>();
        var mockTestService = new Mock<ITestService>();

        var testListViewModel = new TestListViewModel(mockTestService.Object, mockDialogService.Object);

        //Act
        testListViewModel.EditCommand.Execute(2); //this line is failing

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(1, mockDispatcher.Requests.Count);
        var request = mockDispatcher.Requests[0];
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(TestViewModel), request.ViewModelType);
        Assert.AreEqual((2).ToString(), request.ParameterValues["asTestID"]);
    }
}
```

When i run the test it throws MvxIoCResolveException with this call stack. I tried to debug it and my code literally fails on MvxNavigatingObject.ShowViewModel() where the parameter is an object and tries to call **parameterValuesObject.ToSimplePropertyDictionary()**.
In the static function ***ToSimplePropertyDictionary(this object input)*** *propertyInfos* enumerator is null, so it cant call *foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfos)*.

The call stack that I get from running the test is:

```
Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException : Failed to resolve type Cirrious.MvvmCross.Platform.IMvxStringToTypeParser
   at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Resolve(Type t)
   at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Resolve()
   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.MvxSingletonCache.get_Parser()
   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Platform.MvxSimplePropertyDictionaryExtensionMethods.<ToSimplePropertyDictionary>b__7(PropertyInfo property)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Platform.MvxSimplePropertyDictionaryExtensionMethods.ToSimplePropertyDictionary(Object input)
   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxNavigatingObject.ShowViewModel(Object parameterValuesObject, IMvxBundle presentationBundle, MvxRequestedBy requestedBy)
   at App.Core.ViewModels.TestListViewModel.Edit(Int32 asTestID) in TestListViewModel.cs: line 37
   at App.Tests.Test.TestListViewModelTest.TestListViewModel_OnEdit_ShowTestViewModel() in TestListViewModelTest.cs: line 97
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call *ShowViewModel* with a parameter, there are a few different ways to do this. This determines how MvvmCross calls your *Init* method.

- individual simply-Typed parameters
- a single Typed parameter object with simply-Typed properties
- as InitFromBundle() with an IMvxBundle parameter - this last flavor is always supported via the IMvxViewModel interface.

You are calling *ShowViewModel* with an anonymous type, but without property names. These property names must match the parameter names in your *Init* method.

So instead of this:

```c#
private void Edit(int asTestID) { ShowViewModel<TestViewModel>(new { asTestID }); }
```

Do this:

```c#
// simply-Typed parameters
private void Edit(int asTestID) { ShowViewModel<TestViewModel>(asTestID); }
```

Or this:

```c#
//  a single Typed parameter object with simply-Typed properties   
private void Edit(int asTestID) { ShowViewModel<TestViewModel>(new { ID = asTestID }); }
```

See https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/View-Model-Lifecycle#2-init

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to handle your first code fragment in Init(). The second code fragment is similar to mine. 
It is the same as:  `private void Edit(int asTestID) { ShowViewModel<TestViewModel>(new { asTestID = asTestID }); }`

Comment: It should be working if you include the property name in your anonymous type. Are you still getting errors?

Answer (score 4):

```
   // for navigation parsing
   Ioc.RegisterSingleton<IMvxStringToTypeParser>(new MvxStringToTypeParser());
```

see
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Testing